# How to validate user credentials against custom api

Tags: okta

I just create my first Okta application using a dev account.
The app supports saml2.0 to authenticate user.
My goal is to make Okta app as a smal2.0 IdP and having my on-premiesis web app acting as a SP. The flows works great.

As first step to test the flow I created a "user base"(people) in Okta.
Would it be possible to engage from Okta app a custom api (on-premesis) to validate the user credentials (supplied within the Okta built-in login page)?
IOW I'd like to use Okta app simply as saml2.0 IdP, managing the saml2.0 protocol, but I'd like to keep the user base locally.

Answer (score 2):

We do provide SDKs to interact with our API, and you can find them at http://developer.okta.com/docs/sdk/core/api.html.

For instance, the Okta Music Store available at https://github.com/okta/okta-music-store demonstrates how you can authenticate Okta users in an ASP.NET MVC app and automatically provision them into a local database "on the fly" when they sign in.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks @Raphael: that's a great sample to interact with an existing okta userbase, but here I'm trying to accomplish somenthing different. I want to keep the userbase on-prem, have okta app interact with the on-prem userbase during the saml authentication manged by the okta app. The okta app should act as "ExternalLoginProvider", but the user base should not be in okta but "reachable" by okta through api. Basically my use case is the opposite comparing the sample.

Comment: @Crixo, I apologize but I am not sure I understand your use case. If your user database is the source of truth and the location where user passwords are stored, then you are basically building your own identity provider. If that's the case, why do you need Okta in the first place? At this point, I would suggest taking this discussion offline by submitting your question at developers@okta.com. Thank you!